# Input data on Table OnCreate

Tags: google-app-maker

Please what the best way to solve this problem
I have a form to insert data on model_request. 
*(I have other model: model_approver with Type Of Expense, Approver)*

I need that when onCreate event from model_request one other field  receive information from model_approver.

Example:
An user will be create a request and choose a type of expense (Field from model_approver) via dropdown after this when submit , the field ResponsabileApprover [from model_request]   receive Approver [from model_approver].

Dropdowns was working fine
Thanks for clarifications

Answer (score 1):

Call server script with all necessary date from client (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/client#call_a_server_script), and create item on the server side,

**onCreate** event is useful to set some default values (date_created) or validate input data to prohibit creating a new record in a model